# Replace all spaces in a string with '+'

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that contains multiple spaces. I want to replace these with a plus symbol. I thought I could use

```
var str = 'a b c';
var replaced = str.replace(' ', '+');
```

but it only replaces the first occurrence. How can I get it replace all occurrences?

Comment: Are you trying to do URL-encoding of a string? If so, it's better to ask for help with that than just how to handle the spaces.

Comment: @Lasse, I suppose ultimately that is what I'm trying to do as the string that I want to format will eventually become part of a URL. However, I think the question still stands on its own merrit, as replacing all occurrences of a sub-string inside a string isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Right, that was my suspicion too. The answer to that one is: use `encodeURIComponent()`. Don't try to hack it yourself with string replace; it's a lot trickier than you think. This will encode spaces to `%20` rather than `+` though. `%20` is just as valid (in fact more valid, as it works in path components, whereas `+` only means a space in query components), but if you want it to look marginally prettier you can always do a `replace(/%20/g, '+')` afterwards of course. You might be tempted to use `escape()` because it does use `+`, but it also gets all non-ASCII characters wrong—avoid.

Comment: I'll agree with that, the question has merit on its own :) I just wanted to know if that's where you were trying to end up, there might be better solutions for you. But yes, the question is good on its own, no doubt about that. I know enough javascript to scrape by, and that .replace didn't replace all the occurances was news to me.

Comment: Comparison of regex and split/join on tiny and longer strings. http://jsperf.com/replace-characters-in-string

Comment: You waited 4 years to spring this?

Comment: The answer of @Andrew below is the most right one, `str.replace(/\s+/g, '+')` because in case your string contrains chaining whitespaces, it will also replace chaning whiteplaces with one replacement, e.g. `a----b--c-d` will be `a+b+c+d`. It makes more sense. Isn't it?

Comment: In the latest versions of most popular browsers, you can use replaceAll as shown here:

`let result = "a b c".replaceAll(" ", "+");`
`// result is "a+b+c"`

Answer (score 601, accepted):

Here's an alternative that doesn't require regex:

```
var str = 'a b c';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('+');
```

Comment: This selected solution is slower on large replacement compared to the reg expression version. Test with the 3 solutions posted: http://jsbin.com/isadi3/2 Firefox has minimal timing difference, IE has a noticeable difference. So if speed matters and you have a large set of replacements, reg exp is the way to go.

Comment: use str = str.replace(/\s/g, "+");

Comment: @JitendraPancholi that replaces all whitespace, not just the space character. The other regex answer here is fine.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: As per the question, he wants to replace white spaces with + symbol, even your solution is doing the same.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi he wants to replace *spaces*, not "white spaces." In this context I assume by *spaces* he means only the space character, not just any old whitespace like `/s` would match. Particularly because he is doing this in JavaScript, and replacing the space character (but not other whitespace) with the `+` character is a standard way to encode URLs. This is probably why the  regex solution that only replaces space characters has 10x the votes of the one that replaces all whitespace.

Comment: Using a split and join is an overhead if we have large data. So its always good to opt a regular expression for the same if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/aC5ZW/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aC5ZW/3/ having a tab, line feed or form feed in the string, my solution works for all.

Comment: re: overhead: see the last comment on the question. It's significantly less overhead in some browsers for a small amount of data, which is probably what he's dealing with. In some browsers, it's more. Performance is a moot point here, one goes faster and the other goes slower as browsers make tweaks between versions

Comment: re: tabs: you're missing my point. If he's doing what it looks like he's doing, he's not going to *want* it to convert all those characters to `+`. He's only going to want to convert the space character.

Comment: I got your point and also had a look to the comparison, and if we have even 30 replacement, spit/join was apx 90% slower than regex, with 2 replacements, it was only 23% slower.

Comment: It's most likely a URL. You're not going to have 30 spaces in a URL.

Comment: And instead of \s, If i change it to ' ', my solution would still better.

Comment: Yes, a regex solution with a literal space character would probably be better. This answer was meant as an alternative for people who didn't want to use regex. That's why it begins with "Here's an alternative." I can't help that the OP accepted it.

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in comments below the question, url may have that replacements, Even i worked on a project which had the same requirement. I had around 30+ replacement in the url.

Comment: If your projects are using URLs with 30 spaces in them, you have bigger things to worry about than microptimizing string replacements.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: See the last comment in my solution. :D

Comment: Split() and Join() are way overpowered and unnecessary here, when a regex is infinitely more efficient.

Comment: I use a version inspired by the trim polyfill str = str.replace(/[\s\uFEFF\xA0]/g, "+"); ... IE "yeeay"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794936/4429637 this is the best solution.

Answer (score 616):

You need the `/g` (global) option, like this:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/ /g, '+');
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/H6Mrt/).  Unlike most other languages, JavaScript, by default, only replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: this has better readability than the split/join version imho

Comment: Oh, my ... I tried countless times of '/ /g' or something like that, there should be no quotation mark. Astonished me.

Answer (score 134):

```
var str = 'a b c';
var replaced = str.replace(/\s/g, '+');
```

Comment: Cleaner and faster than the chosen solution; works where `/ /g` does not.

Answer (score 105):

You can also do it like:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, "+");
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aC5ZW/).

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, I got a review task to check due to length of content. I assume someone more demanding didn't see explanation and downvoted without bothering to comment. Please put your comment into answer.

Comment: Ok, i have added fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Another possible reason for downvote is that this answer was [already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795130/451518) almost four years ago

Comment: @Jitendra Pancholi Thank you very much, you answer did help me, cuz I had some Japanese :) spaces, that I won't be able to replace by .split(' ').join('+'); Your answer did help me. Thanks man.

Answer (score 34):

Use global search in the string. g flag

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
```

source: [replaceAll function](http://web-design-lessons.com/articles/article/1/Javascript%20Replace%20All%20Instances%20In%20a%20String)

Comment: I have tested many regex above your answer, but your answer is the most right, because it also replaces multiple chainning white spaces.

Comment: Does not work: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/kocufiteva/edit?html,js,console,output) Input: `"hello    !!!"`, expected output: `"hello++++!!!"`, actual output: `"hello+!!!"`

Answer (score 32):

Use a regular expression with the `g` modifier:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/ /g, '+');
```

From [Using Regular Expressions with JavaScript and ActionScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html):

> /g enables "global" matching. When using the replace() method, specify this modifier to replace all matches, rather than only the first one.

Answer (score 16):

You need to look for some replaceAll option

```
str = str.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

this is a regular expression way of doing a replaceAll.

```
function ReplaceAll(Source, stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
    var temp = Source;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);

    while (index != -1) {
        temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
        index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    }

    return temp;
}

String.prototype.ReplaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
    var temp = this;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);

    while (index != -1) {
        temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
        index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    }

    return temp;

};
```

Comment: Wow. Er... there's a *much* simpler idiom for this: `str.split(stringToFind).join(stringToReplace)`.

Comment: Wow is that inefficient.

Comment: @epascarello actually that performs way faster than a regex or above indfedelity :)

Comment: @Casper What browser are you seeing that in? http://jsbin.com/isadi3/edit Looking at the code it looks slow. Just for kicks I coded up a quick test and it is like 100X slower in browsers I tested it in.

Answer (score 7):

## NON BREAKING SPACE ISSUE

In some browsers

(MSIE "as usually" ;-))

replacing space in string ignores the non-breaking space (the 160 char code).

One should always replace like this:

```
myString.replace(/[ \u00A0]/, myReplaceString)
```

Very nice detailed explanation:

http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/

Answer (score -3):

Do this recursively:

```
public String replaceSpace(String s){
    if (s.length() < 2) {
        if(s.equals(" "))
            return "+";
        else
            return s;
    }
    if (s.charAt(0) == ' ')
        return "+" + replaceSpace(s.substring(1));
    else
        return s.substring(0, 1) + replaceSpace(s.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: There are already better solutions provided in the answers here.