# Replacing occurence of character in a string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace occurrence of very `\` with `-` in a string. I am using the following code but it replace only for once occruence:

```
var start = '1/1/12';
startNew = start.replace('/', "-");
```

Result i am getting is: `1-1/12`

Result i want is: `1-1-12`

Comment: Try this: `startNew = start.replace(/\//g, "-");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all spaces in a string with '+'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `reqular expression` with **[replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)** and need to `escape` your forward slash.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/AjFHw/)**

```
var start = '1/1/12';
startNew = start.replace(/\//g, "-");
```

*`/yourtext/g` is syntax for regex for replacing all occurances in replace `function`, since your text is forward slash `/` you have to escape it by putting back `\` slash befor it.*

Answer (score 0):

```
startNew = start.replace(/\\//g, "-");
```

Comment: Typed incorrectly in a hurry. Some problem in editing. It should be .replace(/\//g, "-");

Answer (score 0):

The following would do but only will replace one occurence:

```
"string".replace('/', '-'); // same as you have done
```

For a global replacement, or if you prefer regular expressions, you just have to escape the slash:

```
"string".replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
start.replace(/\\/g,"-");
```