# Replaced %20 in URL with a +

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is it possible to replace the %20 to a + whenever I click the button to add the textbox value to the url.

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var url = "www.urlname.com/results.html?value=";
        url += $('#textbox').val();
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: Does the text box really contain `%20`, or does it contain ordinary spaces?

Comment: Why do you want to use an old style `+` instead of the modern `%20`? It shouldn't make a different to any backend.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var url = "www.urlname.com/results.html?value=";
        url += $('#textbox').val();
        window.location = url.replace(new RegExp(' ','g'),'+');
    });
});
```

Comment: Additionally the textbox string won't have the spaces encoded yet.

Comment: Right you are, the anwser has been updated to replace all matches, and handle spaces instead of html entities

Answer (score 2):

Yep with a regex for all occurrences `$('#textbox').val().replace(/%20/g, '+');`

Comment: Did it? I can't get the replace function to recognize the encoded space as a space in the string.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but this should work. You want to replace the spaces in the value. They're not encoded to the entity at this point.

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var url = "www.urlname.com/results.html?value=";
        var textboxValue = $('#textbox').val();
        textboxValue = textboxValue.replace(/ /g, "+");
        url += textboxValue;
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: This will replace one space with one '+'.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating URL parameters dynamically, you shouldn't use ad hoc substitutions to encode them. Javascript provides the `encodeURIComponent` function to perform all required encodings. So you should write:

```
url += encodeURIComponent($('#textbox').val());
```