# Javascript str_replace not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Trying to do a simple str_replace() in javascript and i can't seem to figure out why it is not working. I am making a form where on sign up the user can select a country and it auto loads up the correct flag for that country. Everything works fine until you select a country that has spaces in the name. The flag images use a - in the place of a space. help...

Javascript Code:

```
$flagimg = '<img id="current_flag" name="current_flag" src="images/icons/flags/United-States.png" width="20px" />';

<script type="text/javascript">

function LoadFlag(FlagName) {
    var oFlag = window.document.getElementById("country");
    var sFlagImg = oFlag.options[oFlag.selectedIndex].value;

    window.document.getElementById(FlagName).src = "images/icons/flags/" + sFlagImg + ".png";
}

</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<select id="country" name="country" onchange="javascript: LoadFlag('current_flag');"><?php echo getCountries(); ?></select>&nbsp; <?php echo $flagimg; ?>
```

Where do I put the str_replace()?

i tried:

```
window.document.getElementById(FlagName).src = "images/icons/flags/" + str_replace(' ', '-', sFlagImg) + ".png";
```

and it does not work.

Image Names:

```
United-States.png
United-Kingdom.png
```

Select Box Option Values:

```
United States
United Kingdom
```

Comment: str_replace() in javascript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace ;)

Comment: str_replace is **not** a (standard) javscript function, it looks like a PHP function

Comment: i googled javascript and read that it was.. hmm... what would be the equivalent then?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here "[Replace all spaces in a string with '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with)" sorry for wasting time.

```
window.document.getElementById(FlagName).src = "images/icons/flags/" + sFlagImg.split(' ').join('-') + ".png";
```

solved it!