# Edit a href tag url before it's clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, href

I have a url that looks something like this:

`https://url.com/a b c`

which is as expected. When the user clicks on this however, it redirects to the wrong link because the link actually has underscores instead of spaces in its url. is there any way to edit this url so that right before the url is clicked, the spaces turn into underscores? The url would look like so:

`https://url.com/a_b_c` when the user clicks it instead of what was above. Below is my attempt:

```
<a target="_blank" style="font-size: 9px" href="https://url.com/{{label}}">[Details]</a>
```

where `label` is equal to `a b c`. I tried the following:

```
<a target="_blank" style="font-size: 9px" href="https://url.com/{{label.replace(" ", "_")}}">[Details]</a>
```

so that `a b c` would turn into `a_b_c` but that didn't seem to work because the curly braces can't actually execute the `replace` function. Any help would be appreciated. If possible, I would also want to append some text to the end of this newly replaced label so it would look like: `a_b_c_new_text` Thanks!

Comment: Why not edit `label` to be the actual string that is needed?

Comment: I can't because the label is returned from my database which I don't want to change for uniformity.

Comment: @Harangue I just tried what you suggested, but the label doesn't even show up in the url when I try to click it.

Comment: Are you sure label actually has data in it?

Comment: @Harangue yes it does. when I use curly braces it has data in it, when I don't, nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was having difficulty getting the global regular expression replace `.replace(/ /g, '_')` working within the curly braces. Instead, I opted for a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with) SO answer.

```
<a ng-href="http://url.com/{{label.split(' ').join('_')}}">Click Me</a>
```

[Here's the Codepen.](http://codepen.io/harangue/pen/qOGNQB?editors=101)

Keep in mind that `ng-href` is better than `href` because it will not throw a 404 before the curly braces are evaluated.

Comment: Angular does not allow regular expression creation within expressions; see the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ju2nmp0/1/)

```js
var $link = document.getElementById('test'),
    $href = test.href;
    
test.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    $href = $href.replace(/%20/g, '_');
    console.log($href);
 this.href = $href;
});
```

```html
<a id="test" href="https://url.com/a b c">Link Data</a>
```

Comment: Not a very angular solution.

Comment: it is client side javascript solution, and the OP  has: html, javascript, href, tags as well as angular!

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the a_b_c is there any way I can parameterize the a b c?