# Count chars without spaces with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to count chars of a text with and with out spaces.

This is my attemp, but count the text without only the first space.

```
<div style="max-width:80%; margin: 10px auto">
<section class="row" ng-app="">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Paste your text for <b>words count</b></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="wordcounter"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Words and characters</div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Characters (with space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter.length}}</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Characters (no space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter.replace(" ","").length}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4Lahp6v/

Comment: I don't understand your question :/

Comment: @DylanMeeus

"This is an example": 18 chars including spaces
"This is an example": 14 chars excluding spaces

But my script return 17 for the second condition

Comment: Which is correct. It is 18 characters if you include the space. Oh but now I see, the 'no space' is wrong

Comment: @DylanMeeus exactly

Comment: You need to use regular expression to replace all spaces from the string. try the below code ```wordcounter.replace(/\s/g, '').length``` will give you the length without spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You only replace one space

### Without regex

The problem is that currently, you are only replacing one space instead of all the spaces in the string. One way you can solve this is by splitting the string by all spaces that are in the string `str.split(" ");` and then joining them together. (glueing the words together again without the space) with `join`.

Change your binding for the counter without spaces like this `{{wordcounter.split(" ").join("").length}}`

```
 <div style="max-width:80%; margin: 10px auto">
    <section class="row" ng-app="">
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Paste your text for <b>words count</b></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="wordcounter"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Words and characters</div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Characters (with space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter.length}}</span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Characters (no space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter.split(" ").join("").length}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go with a regex to also get tab etc.

wordcounter.replace(/\s/g, "")

Comment: And you could try the split-join way as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with and in the answer of @Dylan Meeus

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an Angular custom filter to accomplish this.

```js
angular.module("app", ["core"]);

angular.module("core", []);

angular.module("core").filter('count', function() {
  return function(input, incSpace) {
    input = input || "";
    return incSpace ? input.length : input.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div style="max-width:80%; margin: 10px auto">
    <section class="row" ng-app="">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Paste your text for <b>words count</b>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="wordcounter"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Words and characters</div>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Characters (with space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter | count:true}}</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Characters (no space)<span class="badge">{{wordcounter | count:false}}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>
```